# Glassware uninstalled after google glass reboot

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

I have created a test build of a GDK Glass app that I want to deliver to a few test users. However the app disappears after a reboot. Logcat shows this:

```
08-19 18:18:18.256: I/GlasswareSyncAdapter(978): Uninstalling Glassware ID #6DBADA7634397F00 (com.example.demo).
```

A look at the issue tracker explains that this is caused due to the fact that the MyGlass app didn't install this app and that the app thus isn't linked to the user's account.

Are there any workarounds? With a submission process of over a month how can we get our app tested properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like this issue only occurs when the application you are side loading has been submitted to Google for approval. Just change change the package name of the APK you want to sideload and your problem should be solved.

Answer (score 2):

The submission process should be less than a month at this point. I suggest that once you think you have things working, you submit the app.

Once submitted, you'll be working with the Review Process Team. They are able to create a whitelist (certainly of accounts, and possibly based on a list you can control through a Google Group) of who will be able to see the app on their MyGlass page. This will also allow you to test the app, including the auth flow, using the actual installation process.

Comment: Do you have any more information on this whitelisting?

Comment: Updated. Not sure what more you're looking for, however.