# How do you prevent your ADT loaded Glassware from getting uninstalled?

Tags: google-glass

For last two updates of Glass (XE19.* and XE20*), whenever I load my Glass app onto a device it seems to get auto-deleted after a few hours.  Has anyone else noticed this behavior and have a workaround to prevent it?

Comment: I tried a lot of GLassWare on XE19 and didn't noticed this problem. Maybe you should create a bug report : https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/entry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25388461/glassware-uninstalled-after-google-glass-reboot) seems to indicate that if your apk has the same package name as one that is going through the review process, that it may be removed. Use a package name that is different or go through the review and whitelist process.

**Update**: The whitelist process allows you to permit a select group of people to be able to access the apks as you update them while they are being reviewed. You should be able to ask the review team about this once the process is underway.

Comment: What is the whitelist process?